# Read file by keeping line track in java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have servlet to read log file my jsp call servlet at some interval.I want to add functionality in my servlet so that it read file from line next to last line from previous read.

I have following code but its not working

```
File file = new File("D:\\graph\\temp.log");
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(fr);\

lnr.setLineNumber(count)  // count is the variable keeping track of number of line  
                             previously read.
```

Is it need some extra code ? or is there any other alernative to do the same ?

Comment: Where does count come from? Are you trying to store state in the servlet, the session, client side?

Comment: I have static varible in java file(called by servlet) as this is demo application and here session type of things are not available.

Comment: An advice: try to **not use** static variables for your Java Web Applications, not even in demos, except for constants (like `static final int A_CONSTANT = 9001`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html):

> Note however, that setLineNumber(int) does not actually change the
>   current position in the stream; it only changes the value that will be
>   returned by getLineNumber().

Sounds to me like you'll have to start from the beginning and call readLine in a loop until getLineNumber() is greater than count.

Something like this:

```
File file = new File("D:\\graph\\temp.log");
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
LineNumberReader lineReader = new LineNumberReader(fr);

// skip the lines you don't need 

while (lineReader.getLineNumber() < count) {
    lineReader.readLine();
}

// begin processing input here
```

Comment: ok...... is there any alternative ? or i have to develop my own logic to do same.

Comment: @chetan - I would try calling readLine in a while loop until getLineNumber is >= count. Once you've skipped the lines you don't need, you can start processing the input.  I've never heard of a LineNumberReader before 10 minutes ago... I'm just reading the documentation.

Comment: [LineNumberReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html) is there since JDK 1.1

Comment: @Ravinder - My point was that I've never used a LineNumberReader before, but all you have to do is read the documentation.  The fifth sentence of the documentation explains the OP's problem.  Reading a few more lines of documentation suggests how to solve the proglem.  The first line of my answer includes the exact link you just listed, so... um, thanks ;)

Comment: @jahroy I got you. Just brought forward that it is there since versions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at *RandomAccessFile*. If you keep the count of bytes read. Than followin code will help you.

```
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(fileName,"r");
    byte[] cBuf = new byte[1024];
    long count = offset;
    raf.seek(offset);
    long lineCOunt=0l;
    while(true){
        int lineCOunt  =raf.read(cBuf);
        count +=lineCOunt;
        if(lineCOunt<1024){
            System.out.println((new String(cBuf)).substring(0,i));
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(new String(cBuf));
```